# Understanding OutPuts of Neural Network

Tags: python, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, gated-recurrent-unit

I have a problem in outputs of neural network.

I have 3 layers and in last layer my activation method is softsign and accuracy of it is 97%   but i don't understand output of it.

how can i interpret of it?

```
array([ 2.7876117e-04, -1.1861416e-04, -1.4989915e-04,  1.0406967e-04,
        3.3736855e-04,  2.3964542e-04, -5.1546731e-04, -1.9980034e-05,
       -8.2800347e-05,  9.0804613e-01, -3.4179697e-03,  5.5045313e-03,
        1.9953583e-05,  2.4235848e-04, -1.0185772e-05,  8.0279395e-04,
       -2.2013453e-04, -1.3151007e-03, -7.8655517e-04,  2.5021945e-05,
        3.0023622e-04, -1.2777583e-05,  2.2269458e-04], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

The output has been given in scientific notation. Here e means exponential. Here 1.2e-2 means 1.2^-2